# ¿Cómo validar mi formulario para que le diga al usuario si las contraseñas son iguales?

Tags: validación

He estado buscando en documentación como validar dos contraseñas, pero no entiendo mucho de como hacerlo, apenas me estoy introduciendo en estos lenguajes y me gustaría si alguien me pudiera explicar o enseñar como hacerlo por favor.
este es mi código de HTML pero no se si necesito también JavaScript y como hago para llamar al archivo HTML en java. He visto también que ponen el código de java en el documento HTML pero no entiendo cual es la parte de html y cual es la de java.

Aquí mi codigo añadiendo lo que me proporcionaron

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/registro.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="HS">
        <img src="../img/House_Student.png" class="letter" alt"la">
        </div>

        <div class="titulo">
            <h1>Registrate</h1>
            </div>

<div class="caja_login">
    </div>

    <div class="formulario" align="left">
    <form action="registro.php" name="formulario" id="formulario" method="post">

        <label for="Introduce tu nombre">Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="ej. Luis Ricardo"
        required="" pattern="[a-z-A-Z-á-ú]+"
        title="Unicamente escriba su nombre. No se aceptan numeros en este espacio. Si tiene mas de un nombre escriba unicamente uno.">
<p> </p>
        <label for="Introduce tu apellido paterno">Apellido paterno: </label>
        <input type="text" name="a_paterno" placeholder="ej. Hernández"
        required="" pattern="[a-z-A-Z-á-ú]+"
        title="Unicamente escriba su apellido paterno. No se aceptan numeros en este espacio">

        <label for="Introduce tu apellido materno">Apellido materno: </label>
      <input type="text" name="a_materno" placeholder="ej. Rodríguez"
        required="" pattern="[a-z-A-Z-á-ú]+"
        title="Unicamente escriba su apellido paterno. No se aceptan numeros en este espacio">
<p> </p>

        <label for="Introduce tu edad">Edad: </label>
        <input type="number" name="edad" placeholder="ej. 50"
        required="" min="1" max="120"
        title="Escriba su edad en este espacio. Minimo 1 y maximo 120">

        <label for="Introduce tu Pais">pais: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pais" placeholder="ej. México"
        required="" pattern="[a-z-A-Z-á-ú]+"
        title="Escriba el pais de su procedencia. No se aceptan numeros en este espacio">
<p> </p>
        <label for="Introduce tu Correo">Correo(opcional): </label>
        <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="ejemplo@dominio.com"
        title="Su correo no tiene '@' es necesario que escriba correctamente su correo.
        ejemplo: Brenda12@gmail.com">
<p> </p>
        <label for="Introduce una contraseña">Contraseña: </label>
        <input type="password" requiered="" name="contr" id="contr1"><br>

        <label for="Introduce una contraseña">Confirma tu contraseña: </label>
        <input type="password" requiered="" name="contr2" id="contr2"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Registro"><br>

</div>
<script>
formMain.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { // Escuchar cuando se envíe el formulario
  if (contr1.value !== contr2.value) { // Comprobar si los valores de los inputs son iguales, si no lo son continuar
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir que la página se recargue
    err.innerHTML = "Las contraseñas no coinciden"; // Notificar al usuario
    setTimeout(() => {
      err.innerHTML = " ";
    }, 1200); // Esperar 1.2 segundos y quitar el mensaje
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML es el código que identificas entre los símbolos de `<......>` y js será el código que identifiques dentro de las etiquetas `<script></script>`, ¿puedes agregar que llevas al momento por favor?, por otro lado hablamos en todo caso de JavaScript y no de Java

Comment: Para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta considera editar y mostrar que llevas hecho, si tienes dudas lee [ask]

Comment: el código ya lo puse, pero como soy nuevo en html pues no se si este bien hecho también lo que hice :(

Comment: El tema @Luis es que te comento si llevas hecho algo respecto a comprobar la paridad de las contraseñas (*verificar si son iguales o no*), por que al momento solo señalas que *son requeridas de llenado*, pero lo tienes mal se escribe así: `required`.  Por otro lado faltan detalles como si esto solo se hará con JS o manejarás algún lenguaje como PHP/Java/Python etc.

Comment: pues solo tengo mi html, css y están listos, solo me falta esa validación, con el codigo que me proporciono @anythingg pero como le comente a el, me manda a mi siguiente pagina peor no muestra el mensaje de error, no se que hago mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto con un script simple de javascript:

```js
formMain.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { // Escuchar cuando se envíe el formulario
  if (pass1.value !== pass2.value) { // Comprobar si los valores de los inputs son iguales, si no lo son continuar
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir que la página se recargue
    err.innerHTML = "Las contraseñas no coinciden"; // Notificar al usuario
    setTimeout(() => {
      err.innerHTML = " ";
    }, 1200); // Esperar 1.2 segundos y quitar el mensaje
  }
});
```

```css
.cont {
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Form validation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cont">
      <h1>Validación de forma</h1>
      <p>Inserte contraseñas a continuación
      <form method="POST" action="" id="formMain">
        <p><input required class="form-control" id="pass1" type="password" /></p>
        <p><input required class="form-control" id="pass2" type="password" /></p>
        <p><button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button></p>
        <p id="err" class="text-danger"> </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Edit

El primer bloque de código tiene (JS) tiene que ir al final de la etiqueta `<body>` de tu sitio y entre etiquetas `<script>`, de otra manera,  javascript no podrá leer totalmente el DOM ocasionando errores.

Además no hay forma de que puedas hacer esto sin JavaScript, por la descripción de tu pregunta, te puedo decir que Java es un lenguaje de programación totalmente diferente a JavaScript.

**Ten en cuenta que**

- HTML es la estructura
- CSS el estilizado
- JavaScript es la parte que le añade lógica a la página.

Comment: pues puse lo que me mandaste, pero me lleva a mi siguiente pagina y no muestra el mensaje, ya puse en el if los id de mis inputs. pongo el código.
como añado mi codigo?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade tu código para poder localizar el error y poderte ayudar.

Comment: listo, ya lo edite

Comment: Ya encontré el error, el problema es que "formMain" no está definido, cambia formMain por formulario (en el código JavaScript) o el ID que le pusiste al form.

Comment: bueno si funciona, ya no manda el formulario, pero no muestra le mensaje de que las contraseñas no coinciden

Comment: para eso, añade un `<p>` con el ID "err" en donde quieres que se muestre el mensaje

Comment: ya me quedo!
muchas gracias amigo me ayudaste bastante! <3